# Pass a C# Class Object to a Python file

Tags: c#, python, object, parameter-passing, ironpython

Okay... I'm trying to pass an Object which I declare in C# to a Python file with IronPython.

So this is what I was thinking off:

C# class:

```
public class ParamObj
{
   private string Obj_String;
   private int Obj_Int;

   public ParamObj(string lObjS, string lObjI)
   {
      Obj_String = lObjS;
      Obj_Int = lObjI;
   }

   public string getString()
   {
      return Obj_String;
   }

   public int getInt()
   {
      return Obj_Int;
   }

   public setString(string lStr)
   {
      Obj_String = lStr;
   }

   public setInt(int lInt)
   {
      Obj_Int = lInt;
   }
}
```

So i have my Class.. Now i declare the Class in my C# Project and i pass it to the PYthon file:

```
ParamObj Test_Object = new ParamObj("Test Object from C#", 1337);
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic Test = ipy.UseFile("Test.py");

Test_Object = Test.ObjectAsParam(Test_Object);

Console.WriteLine(Test_Object.getString(), Convert.ToString(Test_Object.getInt()));
```

And now I want to use the Object in my Pythoin file and call it's methods.
So and the Code in my Test.py is as follows:

```
def ObjectAsParam(Obj):

    print Obj.getString()
    print str(Obj.getInt())

    Obj.setString("Changed!")
    Obj.setInt(1338)

    return Obj
```

But my Compiler says that the python script doesn't know the Methods
getString(), getInt() etc.

So is there a way to manage that ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to do some casts somewhere?

Comment: @Davio how can I do that? and where ? (sry I'm not that advanced in Programming )

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Python, but the gist of it is that Python needs to know what type the passed object is in order to be able to call the methods on it. Is there a way to dynamically call these methods? C# has reflection, I don't know if there is something similar in Python.

Comment: @Davio I found out that my Python Script knows the Type of the Object... And i tried to get the Attributes from it with a Reflection... but it still doesn't know the Methods of my ParamObj Class (sry if my english is bad)

Comment: @VanDeath - could you please share the code... because i'm also facing same problem.. i also need to pass C# objet to IronPython.

Comment: @VanDeath - as per below comment, just by making ParamObj class public.. solves the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure ParamObj is a public class.