# How to get WPF Page pointed by NavigationWindow from code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ironpython

I've got a WPF application which embedded IronPython. I'm trying to access my WPF page from Python so I can modify controls defined in XAML from Python but can't manage to do it. I'm using a NavigationWindow to transition from page to page, so I'd like to be able to access the current page pointed to by the NavigationWindow.

I'm capable of accessing controls from a separate Window via Application.Current.MainWindow, but have had no success trying to access a page in the way described above.

Thanks!

Comment: What I think you're really asking is how you can access c# objects (which a WPF page basically is) in iron python. Does this come close to what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340155/pass-a-c-sharp-class-object-to-a-python-file

Comment: I know how to access C# objects, thing is I don't know how to access wpf Page's in particular. When I'm using a Window I can do Application.Current.MainWindow.Content to retrieve the grid (and therefore, its controls) but I have no idea of how to access a page pointed to by a navigationWindow. I'm looking for something like NavigationWindow.Source returning a Page, but there's no such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation window is a content control, if you want to get the page from it you can just use the .content property on the navigation window instance. Or just use the content property from the **NavigationEventArgs** within the onNavigated function.